# Using JSP include to display generated HTML from servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

My servlet calls a method, which generates a HTML file (different content each time), eg. "[Timestamp].html"

In my jsp I use

```
<% String time= (String)request.getAttribute("time");
String address= "resources/"+time+".html";
%>
 <jsp:include page="<%=address %>"/>
```

to show the page.
But it gives an error that the requested resource is not available. If I go to [Timestamp].html, it's there. 
So, I think my problem is because jsp:include gets the file during compilation, not translation, so the file hasn't been closed yet. Any suggestions for a better strategy for including new content?

Comment: <%@ include file="sample.html" %>

Comment: @JetAbe I clarified my question, please see above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the generated string directly to a JSP instead of generating a file. So you are saving IO costs and don't have to handle that error.

Comment: I clarified my equestion, please see above

Comment: my answer is the same... just create a jsp which contains only `<% out.println(myHTMLGenerator.generate()) %>`.

Comment: Okay, I didn't understand it just now. But I got it and solved the problem. Thank you